# WIX heat for registering COM with 64 bit

Tags: com, wix, regasm, heat

I am using the following line to generate the wxs file for registered COM

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\heat.exe" dir "$(SolutionDir)Output" -dr INSTALLFOLDER -cg SapFilesComp -gg -g1 -sf -srd -var "var.outputFolder" -out "$(ProjectDir)\SapHeatFiles.wxs"
```

It works fine, whenever I use regasm 32 bit but whenever I try to register using Regasm (64bit), I got the following error:

> The TypeLib element is non-advertised and therefore requires a parent File element.

Attached the generated wxs file for both cases (*I noticed that in first case "TypeLib" element is nested in the "File" element, while they are sibling in the second case*):

**32 bit**

```
<Component Id="cmp876EABD23BD0B870AA62FA8F8E0FE6B8" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="92ABC2C9-FCBC-403C-BDEF-26FBD3F7246A">
     <File Id="fil45CFD89B1F7C95D68EA24CFD60BA3404" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.outputFolder)\SAP2000Plugin_MALI_CurveLoadV18.tlb">
          <TypeLib Id="{040DE481-6BD0-4EB1-8DAC-32FC97B37E09}" Description="SAP2000 curved load plugin by Mostafa Ali" HelpDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" Language="0" MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="0">
             <Interface Id="{DE52BD0F-3562-39A1-95E2-E55EAB5E9340}" Name="_CPlugin" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
          </TypeLib>
     </File>
</Component>
```

**64 bit**

```
<Component Id="cmp876EABD23BD0B870AA62FA8F8E0FE6B8" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="342BA35D-063E-4C1D-9099-8AD4B78B17FA">
    <File Id="fil45CFD89B1F7C95D68EA24CFD60BA3404" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.outputFolder)\SAP2000Plugin_MALI_CurveLoadV18.tlb" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="TypeLib\{040DE481-6BD0-4EB1-8DAC-32FC97B37E09}\2.0\0\win64" Value="[#fil45CFD89B1F7C95D68EA24CFD60BA3404]" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <TypeLib Id="{00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" Description="OLE Automation" HelpDirectory="SystemFolder" Language="0" MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="0">
        <Interface Id="{4EF6100A-AF88-11D0-9846-00C04FC29993}" Name="FontEvents" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020420-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
        <Interface Id="{7BF80981-BF32-101A-8BBB-00AA00300CAB}" Name="Picture" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020420-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
        <Interface Id="{BEF6E003-A874-101A-8BBA-00AA00300CAB}" Name="Font" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020420-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
    </TypeLib>
    <TypeLib Id="{040DE481-6BD0-4EB1-8DAC-32FC97B37E09}" Description="SAP2000 curved load plugin by Mostafa Ali" HelpDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="0">
        <Interface Id="{DE52BD0F-3562-39A1-95E2-E55EAB5E9340}" Name="_CPlugin" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
    </TypeLib>
</Component>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case someone faces the same problem, I solved the problem by manually nesting Typelib element inside the file element as follows:

```
<Component Id="cmp876EABD23BD0B870AA62FA8F8E0FE6B8" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="D3FCCCC3-FEC9-41B6-9201-E01658CC20B7">
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="TypeLib\{040DE481-6BD0-4EB1-8DAC-32FC97B37E09}\2.0\0\win64" Value="[#fil45CFD89B1F7C95D68EA24CFD60BA3404]" Type="string" Action="write" />
  <File Id="fil45CFD89B1F7C95D68EA24CFD60BA3404" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.outputFolder)\SAP2000Plugin_MALI_CurveLoadV18.tlb" >
    <TypeLib Id="{00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" Description="OLE Automation" Language="0" MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="0" >
      <Interface Id="{4EF6100A-AF88-11D0-9846-00C04FC29993}" Name="FontEvents" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020420-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
      <Interface Id="{7BF80981-BF32-101A-8BBB-00AA00300CAB}" Name="Picture" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020420-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
      <Interface Id="{BEF6E003-A874-101A-8BBA-00AA00300CAB}" Name="Font" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020420-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
    </TypeLib>
    <TypeLib Id="{040DE481-6BD0-4EB1-8DAC-32FC97B37E09}" Description="SAP2000 curved load plugin by Mostafa Ali" HelpDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" Language="0" MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="0" >
      <Interface Id="{DE52BD0F-3562-39A1-95E2-E55EAB5E9340}" Name="_CPlugin" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
    </TypeLib>
  </File>
</Component>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.